# Need a ruby regular exp for matching

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

I'm trying to extract the version from different RPM's list. Below is an example:

```
rpm = "abc-def-ghi-1.1.0-10.el6.x86_64"
```

This variable can have different string values,

```
rpm = "a-b-1.1.1-10.x86_64"
```

My goal is to write a regexp using the "match" method (as below) - though this one does not cover for .el6 aspect.

```
rpm.match(/^#{rpmname_to_match}-(.*).x86_64$/).nil?
```

Comment: What are you trying to match?  The version of the RPM?

Comment: BTW - I also want the extracted version put in a temporary register example:

Comment: yes - the version (as in my examples) 1.1.0-10 and 1.1.1-10

Comment: what would you like to get from an input `ant-apache-resolver-1.6.5-2jpp.2.i386.rpm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain about what you're trying to do with the .el6 part, but if you want a pattern which will only match the numeric part, then try this:

```
([0-9]+(?:(?:\.|-)(?:[0-9]+))*)
```

This will only match a string which starts with one or more digits, then can have any number of sequences which are a period or hyphen followed by one or more digits.

So your final statement might be the following:

```
rpm.match(/^#{rpmname_to_match}-([0-9]+(?:(?:\.|-)(?:[0-9]+))*)(.*)\.x86_64$/).nil?
```